# Control volume of youtube video while opening it through Python

Tags: python, youtube, python-webbrowser

I am opening a YouTube video using the `webbrowser` module of Python:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://youtu.be/xyz")
```

If I want to open this video at a specific start time, I can do so by appending `?t=xs` to the url where `x` is the timestamp at which the video should play when it opens up.

Similarly, is there anything that I could do if I want to set the volume of the video at some level?

Answer (score 2):

As for opening the video on specific `timestamp` you can change your url
like this

```
import webbrowser

timestamp = "?t=YOUR_TIME" #Your time like 32s , 54s or 1m31s
url = "https://youtu.be/xyz" + timestamp
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Hope that helped!

And for controlling the volume , i don't think that there is 
a library for that so No luck

Comment: Nice solution!!